# Laravel 8: POST request is treated as GET

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I have two routes which accept optional parameters:

```
Route::get('application/cedula/{cedula}/{view?}/{model?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController@getCedulaInformationFromPublicServices')->name('application.cedula');
Route::post('application/cedula/{cedula}/verification/{code?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController@verifyApplicationCode')->name('application.confirm');

public function verifyApplicationCode( Request $request, String $cedula, String $code = NULL ) {...}
public function getCedulaInformationFromPublicServices( String $cedula, String $view = NULL, String $model = NULL){...}
```

When I make a POST request to **application/cedula/0001001010/verification**,  without the optional parameter **"{code?}"**, it enters to the GET route.

I know that it's passing **"verification"** to the GET endpoint as the optional parameter **{view?}**, but shouldn't the resquest type be enough to discern between which one to follow despite the endpoint names being similar.

Comment: `application/cedula/0001001010` does not match the `post` route because that needs to be `application/cedula/0001001010/verification`

Comment: @apokryfos sorry, the endpoint has indeed the */verification*, I just missed it in the question.

Comment: Chaining multiple optional parameters is not directly supported. If you did `/example`, but wanted `example` to be the model, not the view, the code cannot handle that. You can do `/null/example` and handle the string `'null'` as the `view`, but at that point, this param is not optional...

Comment: Both routes would match `application/cedula/0001001010/verification` so you need to beware of any redirects that may happen (like e.g. an HTTP to HTTPS redirect or a validation failure redirect) since redirects will change a POST request to GET. Check your developer console in your browser to see if there's a redirection happening

Answer (score 0):

"shouldn't the resquest type be enough to discern between which one to follow despite the endpoint names being similar"? Yes, it's enough. The problem is not about your code. Even I it was like:

```
Route::get('application/cedula/{cedula}/{view?}/{model?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController@getCedulaInformationFromPublicServices')->name('application.cedula');
Route::post('application/cedula/{cedula}/{view?}/{model?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController@verifyApplicationCode')->name('application.confirm');
```

there couldn't be a problem. There would be a problem when there exists more than one potential match like this:

```
Route::post('application/cedula/{cedula}/{view?}/{model?}', ...);
Route::post('application/cedula/{cedula}/verification/{code?}', ...);
```

Now if you make a `POST` request to `application/cedula/0001001010/verification/model1`, the first route comes first so it would be selected. That's because when accessing a route, Laravel goes through your routes top to bottom, until it finds the first match, at which point this route is immediately selected.

But in your case there wouldn't be a problem because your routes are of different request types. Try using `php artisan route:list` to check whether they are cached. If not, the problem is the way you are testing them. I'd recommend something like Postman.

Answer (score -1):

Try to re-arrange your route, putting the routes with constant path first

```
Route::post('application/cedula/{cedula}/verification/{code?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController@verifyApplicationCode')->name('application.confirm');
Route::get('application/cedula/{cedula}/{view?}/{model?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController@getCedulaInformationFromPublicServices')->name('application.cedula');
```

Do not forget to run: `php artisan route:clear`